# How to run delete webrequest using Python?

Tags: python

Currently, I use Powershell to clear cache using the following command:

Invoke-WebRequest https://url -method DELETE

How can I make my Python script do to the same type of delete web request?

Comment: depends on what you're using to make GET requests... are you using `requests` module? (you should).

Comment: I am currently not making any GET requests. I just need to make a delete request.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work:

```
import requests
url = "https://myurl"
response = requests.delete(url)
```